# Save canvas as image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am building an app that would overlay phone cases with designs and save the final image to a folder. The code below works and shows up in the browser but i want to be able to save the image automatically as soon as the page is loaded. The goal is to run this script using a cron so images are generated and saved automatically.

I have tried using canvas.toDataURL and canvas2image to no success? What am i doing wrong? How do i go about achieving it?

```js
(function () {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = 403;
  canvas.height = 800;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  $.when(
    loadImage('./img/pattern.jpg'),
    loadImage('./img/iphone_mask.png'),
    loadImage('./img/iphone_overlay.png')
  ).then( function (patternImage, maskImage, overlayImage){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.drawImage(maskImage, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    ctx.drawImage(patternImage, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.drawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);
         
  }
  );

           

  function loadImage(url){
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function(){
      promise.resolve(image);
    };
    image.onerror = promise.reject;
    return promise;
  }


})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: PS: your inline demo misses link to jQuery and the images references local images. Please add jQuery ref. and upload images to f.ex imgur (or internally in post and use those links).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the base64 encoded image, which you can set as the source of an img tag, where a user can save the image, or send it via AJAX to your server side code which can write the image to a folder.

```
    //save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    //Set it as the source of an img tag
    $('#img').attr('src', dataURL);

    //Send it via AJAX
    $.post('handlerUrl', { image: dataURL }, function(response) {
        //Do something
    });
```

You cannot save it to a folder just via JavaScript.

Comment: Where in the code do i place this code to work? Tried it and nothing happens.

Comment: Try after this line,  `ctx.drawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still does nothing.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunk?